# Redefinition of 'struct __block_literal_1' in Obj-C

Tags: objective-c, struct, compiler-errors, objective-c-blocks, llvm-gcc

I've been working around this problem for a while now and it's really driving me insane. Whenever I declare a block, I get a compile error in Xcode 4.1 compiling with LLVM GCC 4.2:

```
Redefinition of 'struct __block_literal_1'
```

Even examples of blocks copy-pasted from the documentation throw the error:

```
int multiplier = 7;
int (^myBlock)(int) = ^(int num) {
    return num * multiplier;
};
```

I've had several attempts to find a solution to this error to no avail. Any help would be appreciated.

**Update:**

I know it's been a while since I posted, but I will need to tackle this problem sooner or later. I think this has something to do with using static libraries. When a static library with blocks are added to a project, the error is thrown. Will post more details soon.

Comment: This is some C++ lambda extension?

Comment: @pst: No it's a C/Objective-C extension.  You are correct, however, that it is an implementation of lambda expressions.

Comment: Could you provide a minimal test case that reproduces the problem and include the build log that yields the error in your system?